# dividing by zero for sorting process

Tags: mysql, sql, null, zero

Hi I have two tables in my db: users and ratings. I need to sort them by ratings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN ratings ON users.id = ratings.id
ORDER BY ratings.total_value / ratings.total_votes DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Sometimes the total_value value is null, Should i add additional condition to check if these values are null?

Comment: yes. and you must also add condition to check if `total_votes` is zero

Comment: Please don't use `SELECT *`

Comment: at least proofread your post for obvious typos pls. FTFY

Answer (score 0):

I think [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) will work here:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(ratings.total_value, 0) / ratings.total_votes DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COALESCE(ratings.total_value, 0)` to return the first non-null value.  If `ratings.total_value` is `NULL`, then you'd get `0` instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: yeah, but sometomes the ratings.total_votes are null , what with dividing by zero then ?

Comment: Do the same thing, but with a 1 instead of a 0?

Answer (score 0):

My simple test of `select 1 / 0` gives a null value, so I don't even know if you need to care